# What happens on a family PS3 when an account is signed in?

Tags: ps3, psn

My family has a PS3 and we all have a user on it but only one of us has a PSN account (my dad).

But my friend (who has several accounts) and I share one - I was thinking of signing in on it but will I get to keep all my game saves, DLCs and stuff that was bought on my dad's account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Games you bought and downloaded with one account are avaiable to all user accounts on that PS3 system. The games will be at the "Game" menu inside a folder.

If you mean to login in a different PS3, then you have to log in your dad's account and redownload the games, but yes, they will be avaiable to all accounts. Be advised, the number of downloads is limited per system as you can see in [this article](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/338/~/access-purchased-content-on-a-different-playstation-3).

Comment: So I'm only gonna be able to connect to the one on the ps3 that's at my house and his ps3? What about my ps3 vita does that count too?

Comment: Yes, portable systems are included. You can download games again by acessing your dad's psn account on the new system and going on his transfer history, you can download all the content that is in the list again. What you purchased before Nov 17 2011 you can download in 5 different PS3s, PSPs or Vitas and after Nov 17 2011 in 2 different PS3s, PSPs or Vitas.